# Avoid undefined for the component inputs: ngOnChanges or *ngIf

Tags: angular

I have component that recieve array of objects as input:

`<app-order-details [orders]="orders"></app-order-details>`

The `orders` is getting in async way from a API in the `OrdersComponent`, of course.
In the `OrderDetailsComponent` I need to find order with special status, so I have:

`this.specialOrder = this.orders.find(...)`

If I put this code in the `ngOnInit` then `orders` will be undefined, because `orders` object has not passed actually. So, we have two ways:
1. Use `ngOnChanges`
2. Add `ngIf` in the parent component:

`<app-order-details *ngIf="orders" [orders]="orders"></app-order-details>`

What is advantages/disadvatages for 1 and 2 ways?

Comment: You could also pass an observable and subscribe to it, you can filter within your component and assign the resulting observable to a field and then use the async pipe (`| async`) to subscribe in the template directly.

Comment: You can also make `orders` a setter and put the code there to be called when a different value is passed.

Comment: If possible, I would use ngIf: it makes the details component simpler, potentially even immutable. It also feels more logical to me: what's the point of displaying a component supposed to display an order (or an array of orders?) if you have no order yet?

Comment: @JBNizet yeah, make sense

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer never thought about passing observable as Input...need to play with it.